# FabricDnsService is not preferred DNS server on the node

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-service-fabric

I had a local cluster of Service Fabric (SDK version 2.6, Windows 10) running successfully.

I have now a new machine (Windows 10 Pro) and installed Service Fabric SDK 2.8.232. Some time (one minute?) after I start/reset the cluster, the System/DnsService has the warning message "FabricDnsService is not preferred DNS server on the node.".

I tried to install another SDK version (2.7, I could not find version 2.6) and I added a firewall rule to make sure it is not blocking SF (port 53 - UDP, which is the endpoint of the System/DnsService replica), but the problem remains.
I installed SDK version 2.1, but my application has a more recent SF version, which made the application fail, and I do not want to downgrade it.

I can deploy my project successfully with SDK 2.8, but I cannot access the API.

I do not see any DNS-specific error on C:\SfDevCluster\Log\Traces.

1. How can I fix this?
2. Where can I find a more specified error message?
3. Is there any known workaround to make my SF application work?

Edit: I just noticed that I can access the API of my application, so it is not blocking me. Anyway, it would be nice to have that warning message removed.

Answer (score 1):

known issue is: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/496
but the problem is reproduced even after recommended upgrade to SF 6.1

Comment: Can confirm, have replicated this on 6.1.467

Comment: can replicate this on 6.1.472

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/496) issue, and it will be fixed in a coming release.